Python and Selenium unable to find all tables on a page
Being new to Selenium and Python I have been given the task of extracting all the data from three tables on a wikipedia page. In all tests I have been able to get the pertinent data from the fist table but the code is unable to find anything about the 2nd or 3rd table. I know it can't really be this hard but I have been at it for 3 days straight with no advance. What exactly am I missing in my code? I am able to get the page to open and then it spits back that there are only 2 or sometimes one table on the page but I know for a fact that there are three.  The page in question is:
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Entidades_federativas_de_M%C3%A9xico_por_superficie,_poblaci%C3%B3n_y_densidad
And the code I have is as follows:
# Libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
import time
from io import StringIO

# Add debugging statements
print("Starting script...")

# Initialize Chrome options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

# Use webdriver-manager to get the appropriate ChromeDriver
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

try:
    # Start on 2nd Monitor
    driver.set_window_position(2000, 0)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)

    # Initiate Browser
    driver.get('https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Entidades_federativas_de_M%C3%A9xico_por_superficie,_poblaci%C3%B3n_y_densidad')

    # Wait for the page to fully load by waiting for a specific element to appear
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="firstHeading"]'))
    )

    print("Page loaded successfully")

    # Extract data from the tables using specific XPath expressions
    first_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[contains(.//caption, "Entidades federativas de México por superficie, población y densidad")]')
    second_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//table[contains(.//caption, "Población histórica de México")])[1]')
    third_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//table[contains(.//caption, "Población histórica de México")])[2]')

    print("All tables found")

    # First table extraction
    first_table_html = first_table.get_attribute('outerHTML')
    first_table_df = pd.read_html(first_table_html)[0]
    first_table_df = first_table_df.iloc[2:34, :]  # Remove header rows and ensure 32 rows of data
    first_table_df.columns = first_table_df.iloc[0]  # Set the first row as header
    first_table_df = first_table_df[1:]  # Remove the header row from the data
    print("First table extracted successfully")

    # Second table extraction
    second_table_html = second_table.get_attribute('outerHTML')
    second_table_df = pd.read_html(second_table_html)[0]
    second_table_df.columns = ['Pos', 'Entidad', '2020', '2010', '2000', '1990', '1980', '1970', '1960', '1950', '1940', '1930', '1921', '1910']
    print("Second table extracted successfully")

    # Third table extraction
    third_table_html = third_table.get_attribute('outerHTML')
    third_table_df = pd.read_html(third_table_html)[0]
    third_table_df.columns = ['Pos', 'Entidad', '2010', '2015', '2020', '2025', '2030']
    print("Third table extracted successfully")

    # Save to Excel with each table on a different sheet
    with pd.ExcelWriter('mexico_population_data.xlsx') as writer:
        first_table_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Superficie_Poblacion_Densidad', index=False)
        second_table_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Poblacion_Historica', index=False)
        third_table_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Poblacion_Futura', index=False)

    print("Data extraction and Excel file creation successful")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

finally:
    # Close the browser after a delay to see the loaded page
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()

Error example:
Page loaded successfully
An error occurred: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//table[contains(.//caption, "Población histórica de México")])[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=125.0.6422.141); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5b29f734ce3a <unknown>
#1 0x5b29f703645c <unknown>
#2 0x5b29f70825b5 <unknown>
#3 0x5b29f7082671 <unknown>
#4 0x5b29f70c6f14 <unknown>
#5 0x5b29f70a54dd <unknown>
#6 0x5b29f70c42cc <unknown>
#7 0x5b29f70a5253 <unknown>
#8 0x5b29f70751c7 <unknown>
#9 0x5b29f7075b3e <unknown>
#10 0x5b29f731327b <unknown>
#11 0x5b29f7317327 <unknown>
#12 0x5b29f72ffdae <unknown>
#13 0x5b29f7317df2 <unknown>
#14 0x5b29f72e474f <unknown>
#15 0x5b29f733c128 <unknown>
#16 0x5b29f733c2fb <unknown>
#17 0x5b29f734bf6c <unknown>
#18 0x76a0fb094ac3 <unknown>


Did you use ChatGPT or another AI to generate the code above?

I used chatgpt for some assistance but it wasn't getting it.

Using ChatGPT will handicap you in the long run. You won't develop a sense of strategy, architecture, paths of least resistance, and so on. Not to mention AI generated content is banned on SO. Your problem can be solved with 3 (three) lines of code, including imports, and you don't need Selenium nor requests.

Finally found the solution in this code block:
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from io import StringIO

def extract_tables(driver):
    driver.get("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Entidades_federativas_de_M%C3%A9xico_por_superficie,_poblaci%C3%B3n_y_densidad")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="firstHeading"]')))
    print("Page loaded successfully")

    tables = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "table")
    dfs = []
    for index, table in enumerate(tables):
        html_table = table.get_attribute('outerHTML')
        df = pd.read_html(StringIO(html_table))[0]
        dfs.append(df)

    first_table_df = dfs[0]

    # Remove unnecessary rows and columns
    first_table_df = first_table_df.drop([0, 1])  # Drop the first two rows
    first_table_df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in first_table_df.columns.values]
    first_table_df = first_table_df.iloc[:, [3, 4, 6, 7]]
    first_table_df.columns = [
        'Entidad', 
        'Superficie (km²)', 
        'Población (2020)', 
        'Densidad (hab./km²)'
    ]

    print("First table columns after cleaning:", first_table_df.columns)

    second_table_df = dfs[1]
    print("Second table columns before cleaning:", second_table_df.columns)
    second_table_df = second_table_df.drop(columns=second_table_df.columns[0])  # Drop the first column (Pos)
    second_table_df.columns = ['Entidad', '2020', '2010', '2000', '1990', '1980', '1970', '1960', '1950', '1940', '1930', '1921', '1910']

    third_table_df = dfs[2]
    print("Third table columns before cleaning:", third_table_df.columns)
    third_table_df = third_table_df.drop(columns=third_table_df.columns[0])  # Drop the first column (Pos)
    third_table_df.columns = ['Entidad', '2010', '2015', '2020', '2025', '2030']

    return first_table_df, second_table_df, third_table_df

def save_tables(first_table_df, second_table_df, third_table_df):
    with pd.ExcelWriter('mexico_population_data.xlsx') as writer:
        first_table_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Superficie_Poblacion_Densidad', index=False)
        second_table_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Poblacion_Historica', index=False)
        third_table_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Poblacion_Futura', index=False)

    print("Table data extraction and file creation successful")
    ```
I had to first just get everything and then start eliminating rows and columns I didn't want by examining the output.


As you said you are new, Here are a few tips to make your scraping easy and efficient.
I use selenium to get a page source and requests-html to parse it (it's easy).
For your case you need tables with caption tag
You can do something this like:
from requests_html import HTML
# your initial code
src = driver.page_source
html = HTML(html=src)
tables = html.find("table")
tables = [table.html for table in tables if bool(table.find('caption'))]
# do whatever you want to do with table's html


requests-html was last Released: Feb 17, 2019. It's obsolete, and cvasi-unusable on many modern websites.
